# Getting one level up from window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am using window.location.href to get the current full path, for example:

> localhost:8080/myapp/ledger/entries/

but I was wondering if there is a way to get one level up of this URL ex.

> localhost:8080/myapp/ledger/

I've read that I can exclude /entries/ but I need something generic meaning it return the URL one level up without knowing this level, in other words without knowing /entries/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gRwZF/

Comment: What should happen if the path is empty, do you need edge case handling for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var url="localhost:8080/myapp/ledger/entries/"//or whatever other url
var indices = [];
for(var i=0; i<url.length;i++) {
    if (url[i] === "/") indices.push(i);
}
url=url.substring(0,(indices[(indices.length)-2])+1);
alert(url);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P3RgG/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "localhost:8080/myapp/ledger/entries/"
string = string.replace(/([^\/]*\/)$/,"");
```

regex explained:

```
/\//
```

This will look for a slash.

```
/(\/)$/
```

This will look for the last slash in line.

```
/[^\/]*/
```

This will select anything but a slash

```
/([^\/]*\/)$/
```

Above two combined: it will match the last slash and all non-slash characters in front of it.

Comment: `/` is generally called "slash" or "forward slash," not "backslash." Backslash is ` \ `.

Comment: @BrianS Thanks! I should be a bit more careful when naming things.